# Position of text above a line in tikz and overlying of a line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing this circle in tikz and as you can see the appearance of the `$v_m$` on the xaxis and the yaxis are not visible and also the `$V_me^{j\theta}$` is not aligned with the line. Note also that thought the arc have an angle of 50 just like the line's orientation but its not showing the right angle

[image]

Those are the commands that I'm using

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        % Axis
        \draw[thick,->,black] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[below] {$\Re$}; % x axis
        \draw[thick,->,black] (0,-2.5)--(0,3) node[left] {$\Im$}; % y axis
        %circle
        \draw[black,thick] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
        %defining radius points
        \node[black,below] at (2.6,0) {$V_m$};
        \filldraw[black] (2.5,0) circle (2pt);
        \node[black,below] at (0,2.6) {$V_m$};
        \filldraw[black] (0,2.5) circle (2pt);
           
        \draw[ultra thick,->,lava] (0,0) -- (0,0 |- 45:2.5cm)node [black,midway,sloped,above](b1){$V_m\sin(\phi)$}; % UpOn x axis
        \draw[ultra thick,->,myblue] (0,0) -- (45:2.5cm |- 0,0)node [black,midway,sloped,below](b){$V_m \cos (\phi)$}; % UpOn y axis
        \draw[ultra thick,black,->,rotate=45] (0,0) -- (2.5,0)node [black,midway,sloped,above](b5){$V_me^{j\theta}$}; 
        \draw[thick,black](50:2cm |- 0,0) arc (0:50:2);
        \node[] at (20:1.25cm |-20:1.25cm ) {$\phi$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To fix the `$V_me^{j\theta}$` orientation: rotate does not apply to the node (you would have to rotate that explicitly). But it might be better to remove the `rotate` keyword, and use angular coordinates for the path/draw instead `(0,0) -- ++(45:2.5)`

Comment: If you mean \draw[ultra thick,black,->] (0,0) -- node [black,midway,above](b5){$V_m$} ++(\Ang :\Rad);  .. I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: you have to keep the `sloped` key in the node then it should work (works for me)

Comment: it worked, thanks

Comment: @Diana add to my answer below --the arc is 50 but the rotate is 45 degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your MWE all labels are visible, however, they are overlapped with circle and not aligned along vector. This is corrected by using `label` for marking of nodes' names (see MWE below) and use `sloped` option of vector's label. Also use of the `angles` library the drawing and marked of angle is simplified:

```
%\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,    % new
                quotes}                 % new
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
%\usepackage{gensymb} % better is to use siunitx

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
ang/.style = {draw, Straight Barb-Straight Barb, anchor=west,
              angle radius = 8mm, angle eccentricity=1},
arr/.style = {cap=round,-Straight Barb},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, sloped},
every label/.style       = {inner sep=1pt},
                        ]
% axis
\draw[arr]  (-2.7,0)--(3.6,0)   node[below] {$\Re$}; % x axis
\draw[arr]  (0,-2.7)--(0,3) node[left]  {$\Im$}; % y axis
% circle
\draw       (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
% defining radius points
\node (n1) [dot,label= 45:$V_m$] at (90:2.5) {};
\node (n2) [dot,label= 45:$P$]   at (45:2.5) {};
\node (n3) [dot,label=-45:$V_m$] at ( 0:2.5) {};
% vector
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\path[draw=lava, ultra thick, arr] 
    (O) to ["$V_m\mathrm{e}^{j\theta}$"]  (n2.center);
% projections
\path[draw=myblue, very thick, arr] 
    (O) to ["$V_m \cos(\phi)$" ']   (n2.center |- O); % projection on x axis
\path[draw=myblue, very thick, arr]
    (O) to ["$V_m \sin(\phi)$"]     (n2.center -| O); % projection on y axis
% angle
\pic [ang, "$\omega t+\phi$"] {angle = n3--O--n2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your graph looks exactly like I wanted, but when I tried to reproduce it I got the labels shiftd, the $V_m\sin$ and the $V_m\mathrm{e}^{j\theata.. do you know what could be the problem

Comment: @Diana, With the proposed solution you have to get the same result as shown in the answer. If result is different, than you change something in MWE.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
 \definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13} 
 \definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60} 
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    % Axis
    \draw[thick,->,black] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[below] {$\Re$}; % x axis
    \draw[thick,->,black] (0,-2.5)--(0,3) node[left] {$\Im$}; % y axis
    %circle
    \draw[black,thick] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
    %defining radius points
    \node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt,label=45:{$V_m$}] at (2.5,0) 
      {};
    \node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt,label=45:{$V_m$}] at (0,2.5) 
      {};
    \draw[ultra thick,->,lava] (0,0) -- (0,0 |- 45:2.5cm)node 
    [black,midway,sloped,above](b1){\scriptsize $V_m\sin(\phi)$}; % UpOn x axis
    \draw[ultra thick,->,myblue] (0,0) -- (45:2.5cm |- 0,0)node 
    [black,midway,sloped,below](b){\scriptsize $V_m \cos (\phi)$}; % UpOn y axis
    \draw[ultra thick,black,->,rotate=45] (0,0) -- (2.5,0)node 
    [black,midway,rotate=45,above](b5){\scriptsize $V_me^{j\theta}$}; 
    \path[]  (45:1cm |-45:1cm ) edge  [bend left=30]   (45:1cm |- 0,0) ;
    \node[]at  (20:1.25cm |-20:1.25cm ) {$\phi$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So i used this     \draw[thick,black](50:2cm |- 0,0) arc (0:50:2); instead of the command \path to have a better arc .. but why 50 degrees is not working as shown in the figure