# Text above a line in Tikz not working

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code from my previous post in [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561324/position-of-text-above-a-line-in-tikz-and-overlying-of-a-line/561372?noredirect=1#comment1415530_561372), now the problem as you can see in the [image]attached figure is the labels. The code should work, so does it have to do with my Latex version or something. (I'm generating the image below using the code)

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,    % new
                quotes}                 % new
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
%\usepackage{gensymb} % better is to use siunitx

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
ang/.style = {draw, Straight Barb-Straight Barb, anchor=west,
              angle radius = 8mm, angle eccentricity=1},
arr/.style = {cap=round,-Straight Barb},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, sloped},
every label/.style       = {inner sep=1pt},
                        ]
% axis
\draw[arr]  (-2.7,0)--(3.6,0)   node[below] {$\Re$}; % x axis
\draw[arr]  (0,-2.7)--(0,3) node[left]  {$\Im$}; % y axis
% circle
\draw       (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
% defining radius points
\node (n1) [dot,label= 45:$V_m$] at (90:2.5) {};
\node (n2) [dot,label= 45:$P$]   at (45:2.5) {};
\node (n3) [dot,label=-45:$V_m$] at ( 0:2.5) {};
% vector
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\path[draw=lava, ultra thick, arr] 
    (O) to ["$V_m\mathrm{e}^{j\theta}$"]  (n2.center);
% projections
\path[draw=myblue, very thick, arr] 
    (O) to ["$V_m \cos(\phi)$" ']   (n2.center |- O); % projection on x axis
\path[draw=myblue, very thick, arr]
    (O) to ["$V_m \sin(\phi)$"]     (n2.center -| O); % projection on y axis
% angle
\pic [ang, "$\omega t+\phi$"] {angle = n3--O--n2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took liberty and add image, which is produced by MWE which you provide in question. Please, explain us, what on the image is not as you like to have.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the problem with the labels? How do you want them to look?

Comment: Can you see the figure that I get .. I’ve just uploaded it

Comment: But this image is not produced by MWE which you provide in your question. It generate image, which I added after your MWE. Anyway, please check, if you have recent installation of your LaTeX distribution

Comment: Your (actually mine) MWE I tested also in Overleaf. it gets mi the same result as I show in my answer as well as I added to your question.

Comment: I don't know whats wron, but I'm not getting it, maybe someone faced this problem before and can help

Comment: @Diana, try to test MWE in Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/project). And show us obtained result.

Comment: In overleaf its perfect and thats why I am asking, whats happenng .. Maybe I have an old version version thats all... but if you looked at the x-axis its fie, but not the y-axis and the vector.

Comment: My TeX version is 2019 and it has no similar problem as OP problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP's claims can not be reproduced. Given MWE woks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding above and below to the labels as the below code

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,   
                quotes}                
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage{siunitx}     % new
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}
\renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
ang/.style = {draw, Straight Barb-Straight Barb, anchor=west,
              angle radius = 8mm, angle eccentricity=1},
arr/.style = {cap=round,-Straight Barb},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, sloped},
every label/.style       = {inner sep=1pt},
                        ]
                        
 \def\Rad{3.25}                       
                        
% axis
\draw[arr]  (-\Rad-.3,0)--(\Rad+.5,0)   node[above] {$\Re$}; % x axis
\draw[arr]  (0,-\Rad-.3)--(0,\Rad+.5) node[left]  {$\Im$}; % y axis
% circle
\draw       (0,0) circle (\Rad cm);
% defining radius points
\node (n1) [dot,label= 45:$V_m$] at (90:\Rad) {};
\node (n2) [dot,label= 45:$P$]   at (45:\Rad) {};
\node (n3) [dot,label=-45:$V_m$] at (0:\Rad) {};
% vector
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\path[draw=lava, ultra thick, arr] 
    (O) to ["$V_m\mathrm{e}^{j\theta}$" above]  (n2.center);
% projections
\path[draw=myblue, very thick, arr] 
    (O) to ["$V_m \cos(\phi)$" below]   (n2.center |- O); % projection on x axis
\path[draw=myblue, very thick, arr]
    (O) to ["$V_m \sin(\phi)$" above ]     (n2.center -| O); % projection on y axis
% angle
\pic [ang, "$\footnotesize{\omega t+\phi}$"] {angle = n3--O--n2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty and add images produced with your code in answer. As you can observe, the result of your "solution" is the very same as you can obtained from my code used in your question. So I wonder, what you actually solved?

Comment: When I use my app it produces the figure displayed in my post, which has a problem with labels as you can observe in my original post. Now, your code works fine with overleaf, but not when I use my app. Once I added the above the code worked in my app and produced the exact same result that I got when I used overleaf.

Comment: Sorry, but your claims not hold.