# How to plot a "polar coordinate" graph

Tags: plot

My goal is to plot a cartesian plane with a circle centered around the origin, a right triangle touching the origin inscribed in the circle, which has an angle named theta and sides named x and y, the axes shall not be named. Possibly in every single quadrant. I want to make such a plot in order to sort of "explain" the polar coordinates and show how to get the formulae.

I know a lot of mathematical LaTeX, but nothing about plotting such graphs whatsoever and would greatly appreciate your help.

**EDIT:**
Okay, I'm terribly sorry, that my text was apparently a bit unclear. I added a picture.
[image]

I also want to do a similar picture for three dimensional spherical coordinates. I found [this](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/the-3dplot-package/) and changed it a little bit up. As follows

```
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\draw[-stealth,color=red] (O) -- (P);
\draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
\draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
\tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\phi$}
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
\draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:90:\rvec);
\draw[dashed] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:90:\rvec);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\phivec}{\thetavec}{0}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

But now, I still want to have dotted lines going from the projetion of the point P to the xy-axis Pxy to the x and y axes.

Comment: "A picture is worth a thousand words". Apparently you do not know how to provide a minimal working example ^^

Comment: Do you want something like a figure explaining trigonometric functions through the trigonometric circle?

Comment: I admit, it may be hard to follow without a picture. I would like to have something like this but sincely made with LaTeX.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/561332/197451 -- and -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553647/197451

Comment: Karl's students know how to draw this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question of new-comers as usual. Asymptote has `margin` option, so the arrowhead just touches to the target. TikZ has nice built-in `stealth` arrow.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(2cm);
real a=40;
pair M=dir(a);
draw((M.x,0)--M,red+dashed); label("$x$",(M.x,0),S);
draw((0,M.y)--M,red+dashed); label("$y$",(0,M.y),W);
draw(arc((0,0),.2,0,a),Arrow(TeXHead), TrueMargin(0.5 linewidth(currentpen))); 
label(scale(.8)*"$\theta$",.3dir(a/2));
draw(Label(scale(.8)*"$r$",align=.5NW),(0,0)--M,red);
draw(unitcircle,blue);
draw((-1.25,0)--(1.25,0),Arrow(TeXHead));
draw((0,-1.25)--(0,1.25),Arrow(TeXHead));
label("$O$",(0,0),SW);
shipout(bbox(2mm,invisible));
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\def\a{40}
\path 
(0,0) coordinate (O)
(\a:1) coordinate (M);
\draw[dashed,magenta] 
(O-|M) node[black,below]{$x$} --(M)
(O|-M) node[black,left]{$y$} --(M);
\draw[-stealth] (0:.25) arc(0:\a:.25);
\path (\a/2:.35) node[scale=.8]{$\theta$};
\draw[magenta] (O)--(M) node[midway,above]{$r$};
\draw[->] (-1.25,0)--(1.25,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1.25)--(0,1.25);
\draw[teal] (O) circle(1) node[black,below left]{$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Well actually, I forgot one thing. How can I add a little $r$ above the magenta radial line?

Comment: you can use `\draw[magenta] (O)--(M) node[midway,above]{$r$};`

Comment: Could you please see my edit again? I tried to do these dotted lines similarly as you did so \draw[dashed, black] (O-|Pxy) node[black,left]{$x$} -- (Pxy) but it did not work. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I read your edit. You can make a new question after checking related post on this site.